# using different package names in one google play developer account

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to use different package names in one Google Play Developer account?

For example my applications are:

```
app 1 : com.example.app1

app 2 : com.abcde.app2

app 3 : com.xyzt.app3
```

Can i publish all that applications with one Google Play Developer account? 
**OR** do i have to use the same package name for all the apps as follows:

```
app 1 : com.example.app1

app 2 : com.example.app2

app 3 : com.example.app3
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible to use different package names in one Google Play Developer account, but each application must have unique package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** `package name` is the same as `application id`

> can i publish all that applications with one Google Play Developer
>   account?

Yes, you can. **In fact, you WILL HAVE TO keep separate package names for each app.** Every application you add under your developer account should have a unique application id (package name). You cannot even use an application id that has already been published by another developer. Google will tell you if that accidentally happens and not allow you to upload until you change it to something unique.

> or do i have to use the same package name for all the apps.

That is not possible. *(Refer answer to first question above)*

Comment: i understand. but one more question: is "com.example" unique just for my developer account? can anyone use my domain as package name? for example my apps are com.example.app1, com.example.app2, com.example.app3 .  can another developer account use com.example.app4 for his app?

Comment: It has to be unique across the store. Not just your account.

Comment: that means, i can use for example com.twitter.myapp ?

Comment: No that might violate a policy. If twitter notices or google detects it during a review they might raise concerns. It may lead to suspension of your app. Go through the developer policy thoroughly before you upload.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application name is also it's ID on the play store it's just have to be unique.
Since the upper 3 names differ from each other you can post those app under the qualified names. 

**PS**

Just for you to know the com.name is there since alot of apps also have a company that runs them and since the companies website is probabley uniqeue it should also be uniqueue on the store...